# Построить ломаную со стрелками каждые n метров

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Есть такая ломаная:
https://jsfiddle.net/80he6rvq/

```
 var myPolyline = new ymaps.Polyline([
            // Указываем координаты вершин ломаной.
            [55.80, 37.50],
            [55.80, 37.40],
            [55.70, 37.50],
            [55.70, 37.40]
        ], {
            // Описываем свойства геообъекта.
            // Содержимое балуна.
            balloonContent: "Ломаная линия"
        }, {
            // Задаем опции геообъекта.
            // Отключаем кнопку закрытия балуна.
            balloonCloseButton: false,
            // Цвет линии.
            strokeColor: "#000000",
            // Ширина линии.
            strokeWidth: 2,
            // Коэффициент прозрачности.
            strokeOpacity: 1
        });
```

Как я могу сделать на ней стрелки каждое n расстояние?

Пример:

[image: Пример]

В гугл картах это решается очень легко - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305497/how-to-draw-an-arrow-on-every-polyline-segment-on-google-maps-v3

Есть ли возможность повторить это на Яндекс.Картах?

Comment: С помощью ломанной повторить не получится. Яндекс предлагает [создавать модули для кастомных фигур](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/arrow). Способ попроще — повторить геометрию вашей линии с помощью полигона, [залитого спрайтом стрелки](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon_with_image).